# Error "The getter 'url' was called on null." What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: flutter, dart

> 1. This is my model for services.

```
'''
class ServiceItem {  

final String id;
  final String serviceName;
  final String url;

  ServiceItem({this.id, this.serviceName, this.url});
}

List<ServiceItem> items = [
  ServiceItem(
    id: '1',
    serviceName: 'Shopping Bag',
    url: "./assets/img/shopping_bag.png",
  ),
  ServiceItem(
    id: '2',
    serviceName: 'Order Lists',
    url: "./assets/img/order.png",
  ),
  ServiceItem(
      id: '3',
      serviceName: 'Everyday Subscription',
      url: "./assets/img/everyday.png"),
  ServiceItem(
    id: '4',
    serviceName: 'Handyman',
    url: "./assets/img/handyman.png",
  ),
];

'''
```

> 2. Instantiated the model class on the Page.

```
'''
ServiceItem _serviceItem;
'''
```

> 3. Calling the properties in the Widgets.

```
'''
Image(image: AssetImage(_serviceItem.url[index])),
Text(_serviceItem.serviceName[index]),
'''
```

> 4. Getting Error "The getter 'url' was called on null." and  Getting Error "The getter 'serviceName' was called on null." and

What Am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You only instantiated the class but do not set any value to it, for sure it is null.

Comment: I think you 're trying to do this `Image(image: AssetImage(items[index].url)),
Text(items[index].serviceName),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Image(image: AssetImage(items[index].url)),
Text(items[index].serviceName),
```

OR

```
_serviceItem=items[index];
Image(image: AssetImage(_serviceItem.url)),
Text(_serviceItem.serviceName),
```